# Using QGIS Server on Windows

Tags: qgis

I try to set qgis-server by **OsGeo4w-install from internet** on windows.
But the browser show link this [![brower show][1]][1] when I visit *http://localhost:8888/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?MAP=C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/bin/world.qgs&LAYERS=countries&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=400&HEIGHT=200*.
and the Apache **error.log** show:

````
[Tue Mar 16 01:05:52.653976 2021] [cgi:error] [pid 13192:tid 1852] [client ::1:54190] AH01215: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db\r: C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe
[Tue Mar 16 01:05:52.653976 2021] [cgi:error] [pid 13192:tid 1852] [client ::1:54190] AH01215: proj_get_authorities_from_database: Cannot find proj.db: C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe
[Tue Mar 16 01:05:52.653976 2021] [cgi:error] [pid 13192:tid 1852] [client ::1:54190] AH01215: proj_as_wkt: Cannot find proj.db: C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe
[Tue Mar 16 01:05:52.654975 2021] [cgi:error] [pid 13192:tid 1852] [client ::1:54190] AH01215: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db: C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe
[Tue Mar 16 01:05:52.654975 2021] [cgi:error] [pid 13192:tid 1852] [client ::1:54190] AH01215: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db: C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe ```

If it is a GDAL or proj problem, then how do I fix it?

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFN0C.png
````

Answer (score 1):

You need to set in your Apache virtualhost `PROJ_LIB` variable environment with something like

```
SetEnv PROJ_LIB "C:\OSGeo4W64\share\proj"
```

You QGIS fails to load because looking for `proj.db` and Apache tells you `Cannot find proj.db`. I could be wrong but the file should be in `C:\OSGeo4W64\share\proj` (if not find it and change path to it directory to defined `PROJ_LIB`)

`PROJ_LIB` environment variable is the way to tell where to look for projections definitions.